# After login data user lost

Tags: vue.js

Can you help me please?After login I got given but they are some time lost.Can I save it?
backend i have django rest and good work.gettAPi it is axios

```
created() {
          console.log(this.loggedIn);
          gettAPI.get('/customers/', { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.$store.state.accessToken}` } })
          .then(response => { 
            this.$store.state.profile = response.data.data,
            this.$store.state.nameuser=this.$store.state.profile.[0].user.username
            console.log(this.riz)

           
            
            
            console.log(this.$store.state.profile)

          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
          
          })    
                
              
              
              
        
          

         
            
        },
```

Comment: Hello, your question sounds pretty unclear, could you please explain what does work and what does not work, are there any relevant server errors or errors in console?

Answer (score 0):

You have to store a property in Vuex
store.state.isLoggedIn:true
Also useling a Jwt authentication require a token to be stored.